# How to pass a value from code behind to javascript function in WP7

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-phone-7, dom-events

I am attempting to implement a search feature for text displayed in a webbrowser control. I have a search function which works correctly to highlight text, although it currently accomplishes this by creating a search bar in javascript in the webbrowser. The problem with this is that depending on the size of the page, the javascript search bar is always a different size, which is very confusing. I would like to be able to pass a search value entered by the user in a textbox in my WP7 application to this javascript function, and then have it simply highlight the values. I do not know how to pass a value to a javascript function though, and I am having much difficulty making this work.

Javascript search function (in a text file)

```
javascript:(
function()
{
function G()
{
    var pf=doc.getElementById('pf');
    var qt=doc.getElementById('qt');
    if(null==pf)
    {
        pf=doc.createElement('div');
        pf.id='pf';
        var s=pf.style;
        s.position='absolute';
        s.zIndex='99';
        s.top=(scT||scBT)+'px';
        s.left=(scL||scBL)+'px';
        s.width='100%';
        s.backgroundColor='#FFFF00';
        pf.appendChild(doc.createTextNode('Search: '));
        qt=doc.createElement('input');
        qt.id='qt';
        qt.type='text';
        pf.appendChild(qt);
        var sb=doc.createElement('input');
        sb.type='button';
        sb.value='Find';
        sb.onclick=function()
        {
            P(qt.value)
        };
        pf.appendChild(sb);
        doc.body.appendChild(pf);
    }
    else
    {
        pf.style.display='inline';
        count=0;
    }
}
function P(s)
{
    document.getElementById('pf').style.display='none';
    if(s==='')
        return;
    var n=srchNode(document.body,s.toUpperCase(),s.length);
    alert("Found "+count+" occurrence"+(count==1?"":"s")+" of '"+s+"'.");
    pf.parentNode.removeChild(pf);
    return n;
}
function srchNode(node,te,len)
{
    var pos,skip,spannode,middlebit,endbit,middleclone;
    skip=0;
    if(node.nodeType==3)
    {
        pos=node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(te);
        if(pos>=0)
        {
            spannode=document.createElement("SPAN");
            spannode.style.backgroundColor="red";
            middlebit=node.splitText(pos);
            endbit=middlebit.splitText(len);
            middleclone=middlebit.cloneNode(true);
            spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
            middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode,middlebit);
            ++count;
            skip=1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(node.nodeType==1&&node.childNodes&&node.tagName.toUpperCase()!="SCRIPT"&&node.tagName.toUpperCase!="STYLE")
            {
                for(var child=0;child<node.childNodes.length;++child)
                {
                    child=child+srchNode(node.childNodes[child],te,len);
                }
            }
        }
        return skip;
    }
    var count=0,scL=0,scT=0,scBL=0,scBT=0;
    var w=window,doc=document;
    if(typeof doc.body!='undefined'&&typeof doc.body.scrollLeft!='undefined')
    {
        scBL=doc.body.scrollLeft;
        scBT=doc.body.scrollTop;
    }
    if(typeof doc.documentElement!='undefined'&&typeof doc.documentElement.scrollLeft!='undefined')
    {
        scL=doc.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        scT=doc.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    G();
})()
```

Find on Page method

```
public void FindOnPage()
    {
        var resource = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Resources/FindOnPage/FindOnPage.txt", UriKind.Relative));
        string text;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resource.Stream);

        //while((text = sr.ReadToEnd()) != null) 
        if ((text = sr.ReadToEnd()) != null)
        {
            TheWebBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", text);
        } 
    }
```

Assuming that I had a searchbar named **SearchBar**, how would i pass the text to the user input through the javascript function, so that the text will be highlighted? I have no experience with javascript, so any assistance will be greatly appreciated on the subject!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way of passing it. 
You can string replace the parameter before calling eval, first modify your javascript like this

```
javascript:(
function(searchString)
{
function P(s)
{
    if(s==='')
        return;
    var n=srchNode(document.body,s.toUpperCase(),s.length);
    alert("Found "+count+" occurrence"+(count==1?"":"s")+" of '"+s+"'.");
    return n;
}
function srchNode(node,te,len)
{
    var pos,skip,spannode,middlebit,endbit,middleclone;
    skip=0;
    if(node.nodeType==3)
    {
        pos=node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(te);
        if(pos>=0)
        {
            spannode=document.createElement("SPAN");
            spannode.style.backgroundColor="red";
            middlebit=node.splitText(pos);
            endbit=middlebit.splitText(len);
            middleclone=middlebit.cloneNode(true);
            spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
            middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode,middlebit);
            ++count;
            skip=1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(node.nodeType==1&&node.childNodes&&node.tagName.toUpperCase()!="SCRIPT"&&node.tagName.toUpperCase!="STYLE")
            {
                for(var child=0;child<node.childNodes.length;++child)
                {
                    child=child+srchNode(node.childNodes[child],te,len);
                }
            }
        }
        return skip;
    }
    var count=0,scL=0,scT=0,scBL=0,scBT=0;
    var w=window,doc=document;
    if(typeof doc.body!='undefined'&&typeof doc.body.scrollLeft!='undefined')
    {
        scBL=doc.body.scrollLeft;
        scBT=doc.body.scrollTop;
    }
    if(typeof doc.documentElement!='undefined'&&typeof doc.documentElement.scrollLeft!='undefined')
    {
        scL=doc.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        scT=doc.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    P(searchString);
})("#search#")
```

Then in your C# replace #search# with your SearchString.

```
public void FindOnPage()
    {
        var resource = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Resources/FindOnPage/FindOnPage.txt", UriKind.Relative));
        string text;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resource.Stream);

        //while((text = sr.ReadToEnd()) != null) 
        if ((text = sr.ReadToEnd()) != null)
        {
        text = text.Replace("#search#",SearchBar.Text); //Replace SearchBar.Text with the string you want to search    
        TheWebBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", text);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your solution, but I am getting an error on line `TheWebBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", text);` stating `SystemException was undhandled` and below that `An unknown error has occurred. Error: 80020101.` It seems though that replacing #search# with the SearchBar text is in fact working though.

Comment: Sorry , i did a small mistake, the code is still refering to pf which no longer exists, i will remove the references to pf and correct the code. You can take the edited code

Comment: It works great! I appreciate your help. Now I'm assuming if I wanted to remove the highlighting i can just pass the javascript function an empty search string?

Comment: Mostly that may not work, to remove the highlighting you may have to write another function that searches for your span, and removes the background color or puts a transparent color. Give your span an ID, look for your span using var myspan=doc.getElementById('spanID'); and then set the background color to transparent.